# YA or Juvenile short story anthology (textbook?)

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

When I was in middle school (early 2000s) I remember finding an English textbook full of short stories, plays, and other things. They would be followed by a brief questionnaire before moving onto the next story or drama. I know that:

1. One of the stories was "Welcome Home, Jellybean" by Marlene Fanta Shyer. I'm not sure if it was an excerpt or the script from the TV special. It was not as long as the original novel I believe.
2. There was a drama about an American family who either hire a Japanese maid or take in a Japanese girl after the events of WWII and the atomic bomb. The boy thinks she is a spy and tries to take a picture of her to see if she'll glow in the dark. I'm unsure if the girl was ever a bomb victim or if he was assuming since the drama was about racism.
3. The edition of the book I had was an orange softcover and not very large. It couldn't have been more than 900 pages I estimate and would fit into a backpack. I think it was part of a series
4. The time I had the book was about 2004. Since Welcome Home Jellybean was published in 1978, I estimate that the collection was published between 1978 to 2003.
5. I'm not sure if it was a textbook intended for children, juvenile, secondary, middle grade or young adult. Each story seemed to have a lesson but I think the language was too complex for a child. I think it was either YA or secondary.
6. There were other stories in the collection but these are the two I remember. The questions in the textbook were blank so I believe I had the student edition and not the teacher one.